# UWP Button click from ListViewItem

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, user-controls

I really hope someone with more experience can give me a few pointers.

I have the following setup for a UWP project:

- A `ListView` declared in XAML inside my application page, `Tubes.xaml`:

  ```
  <ListView Name="TubesGrid"
                ItemsSource="{x:Bind TubeItems, Mode=TwoWay}"
                ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TubeTemplateSelector}"
                IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                ItemClick="TubesGrid_ItemClick"
                SelectionChanged="TubesGrid_SelectionChanged">
  ```
- A `UserControl` as a template for the `ListViewItem` (`UserControl.Resources`):

  ```
  <local:TubeTemplateSelector x:Key="TubeTemplateSelector"
                              TubeTemplate="{StaticResource TubeTemplate}">
  </local:TubeTemplateSelector>
  <DataTemplate x:Key="TubeTemplate" x:DataType="data:Tube">
      <local:TubeTemplate HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FavoritesNumber="{x:Bind SpaceLength, Mode=OneWay}"></local:TubeTemplate>
  </DataTemplate>
  ```
- Inside the `TubeTemplate` I have a button, beside other views:

  ```
  <Button Name="RemoveTube"
          Click="RemoveTube_Click"
      <Image
              Source="../Assets/xIcon.png"
              Stretch="None">
      </Image>
  </Button>
  ```
- What I'm trying to achieve:

  1. When I click the `ListViewItem` I want the `ItemClick` event to be triggered. This works.
  2. But when I click on the Button that's inside the `ListViewItem` I want a different event to be triggered inside the main page.

The idea is to click on an item to select it, but when I click the button inside the item, I want that item to be removed.

What are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If looks like are doing this without using viewmodels, then you could add an event to the TubeTemplate control.

```
 public event EventHandler Closed;
```

When the close button is clicked, you would fire the event.

```
private void RemoveTube_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Closed?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty); // Even better would be to give the item clicked (the data context)
}
```

Then, from within your MainPage you could subscribe to the event.

```
<local:TubeTemplate HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                    Closed="TubeTemplate_Closed">

</local:TubeTemplate>
```

In the `TubeTemplate_Closed` method, you could remove the item clicked.

```
private void TubeTemplate_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var element = (FrameworkElement)sender;
    var tube = (Tube)element.DataContext;

    TubeItems.Remove(tube);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> The idea is to click on an item to select it, but when I click the button inside the item, I want that item to be removed.

The better way is bind button command property with MainPage command method, and process the data source in the code behind. you could refer the following code.

**Code Behind**

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        MakeDataSource();
        this.InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

    }
    public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; set; }

    private void MakeDataSource()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "Nico","CCor","Jack"};

    }
    public ICommand BtnCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new CommadEventHandler<object>((s) => BtnClick(s));
        }
    }

    private void BtnClick(object s)
    {
        Items.Remove(s as string);
    }
}
public class CommadEventHandler<T> : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public Action<T> action;
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this.action((T)parameter);
    }
    public CommadEventHandler(Action<T> action)
    {
        this.action = action;

    }
}
```

**Xaml code**

Please note we need pass current focus listview item parameter to command method and remove it from data souce.

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="RootGrid">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" x:Name="MyListView">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                            Margin="0,0,30,0" 
                            Content="Favorite" 
                            Command="{Binding ElementName=MyListView,Path=DataContext.BtnCommand}" 
                            CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I'm going to try this solution right now.