# How to reference parent DataContext in user control [C++/winrt]

Tags: c++-winrt

**Edit: Solved via blank user control, not custom control (See below solution)**
I'm basically trying to modularize complex XAML stuff away from MainPage into a user control, hence I need to figure out how to inject the local DataContext within MainPage.Xaml into my user control.

Following the MSDN Doc's tutorial for custom user controls, I have a custom control in my MainPage.xaml file, called NutriDetailsControl.

```
// MainPage.xaml


...<ListBox x:Name="ItemList" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Basket}" RelativePanel.Below="AddDelCol"
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:BasketItem"> 
            <StackPanel GotFocus="ItemGotFocus" Orientation="Horizontal">
               <Button Content="Delete" Click="DeleteItemClickHandler"/>
               <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{x:Bind Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
HERE------->   <local:NutriDetailsControl Background="Red" MyItem="Hello, World!" MyBasketItem="x:Bind ???"/>
            ...
         ...
      ...
   ...
...</ListBox>
```

MyItem is a string, and I am able to access it within the custom user control, but I can't access MyBasketItem, which is a DependencyProperty of type BasketItem (ViewModel variable within the local DataContext). In Generic.Xaml, I've tried to access BasketItem's data via binding locally, and through the DependencyProperty I passed in (MyBasketItem),

```
<!-- \Themes\Generic.xaml -->
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:NutritionBasket">

 <Style TargetType="local:NutriDetailsControl" >
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:NutriDetailsControl">
                    <Grid Width="30" Height="30" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
(THIS WORKS)------>     <!--<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{TemplateBinding MyItem}"/>-->
                        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content=">">
                            <Button.Flyout>
                                <Flyout>
                                    <Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
                                        <Style TargetType="FlyoutPresenter">
                                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Disabled"/>
                                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
                                            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="True"/>
                                            <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Cycle"/>
                                        </Style>
                                    </Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
                                    <StackPanel>
    LOOK HERE ---------------->          <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}"/>
     AND HERE ---------------->          <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding MyBasketItem.Name}"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Flyout>
                            </Button.Flyout>
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

For the first line, I am trying to access BasketItem->Name() via the local DataContext. I am getting an error "This Xaml file must have a code-behind to use {x:Bind}".

For the second line, when I am passing in BasketItem as a DependencyProperty within NutriDetailsControl.h, I am getting "MyBasketItem is not supported in a Windows Universal project"

I know that for Name(), I can simply pass it in as a DependencyProperty; my GOAL is to reference another variable, BasketItemNutri() which is a sub-ViewModel variable of BasketItem. So I need to figure out a way to either pass in BasketItem, or BasketItemNutri, from the MainPage into custom user control.

Any help would be appreciated. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**

I wasn't able to get the Nico's solution to work for me, since I still needed to somehow bind within NutriDetailsControl.xaml to MyBasketItem, and no permutation I tried seemed to work.

After reading the [Data Binding in Depth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth), I thought maybe I should forget about this whole custom control thing situation, and just go with a blank user control, called NutriControl.

I created a DependencyProperty in NutriControl.idl (blank user control) by adding

```
static Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyProperty MyBasketItemProperty{ get; };
        BasketItem MyBasketItem;
```

(Note that **MyBasketItem**Property and **MyBasketItem**; must be the same). A DependencyProperty of a user control, "exposed" through the NutriControl.idl file, is basically like a box that you can put data into from other Xaml files (like MainPage.xaml). The data can be text, class objects (including your viewmodels), etc.

```
// Mainpage.Xaml
<local:NutriControl MyBasketItem="{x:Bind}"/>
```

"x:Bind" binds to the local DataContext (DataType??), which was a BasketItem here, so I didn't need to specify anything else.

```
// NutriControl.h
...other stuff...
struct NutriControl : NutriControlT<NutriControl>
    {
        NutriControl();

        NutritionBasket::BasketItem MyBasketItem()
        {
            return winrt::unbox_value<NutritionBasket::MyBasketItem>(GetValue(m_myBasketItemProperty));
        }

        void MyBasketItem(NutritionBasket::MyBasketItem const& value)
        {
            SetValue(m_myBasketItemProperty, winrt::box_value(value));
        }

        static Windows::UI::Xaml::DependencyProperty MyBasketItemProperty() { return m_myBasketItemProperty; }

        static void OnMyBasketItemChanged(Windows::UI::Xaml::DependencyObject const&, Windows::UI::Xaml::DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs const&);

    private:
        static Windows::UI::Xaml::DependencyProperty m_myBasketItemProperty;
    };
}
...other stuff...
```

```
// NutriControl.c
    NutriControl::NutriControl() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Windows::UI::Xaml::DependencyProperty NutriControl::m_myBasketItemProperty =
        Windows::UI::Xaml::DependencyProperty::Register(
            L"MyBasketItem",
            winrt::xaml_typename<NutritionBasket::BasketItem>(),
            winrt::xaml_typename<NutritionBasket::NutriControl>(),
            Windows::UI::Xaml::PropertyMetadata{ winrt::box_value(L"default label"), Windows::UI::Xaml::PropertyChangedCallback{ &NutriControl::OnMyBasketItemChanged } }
    );

    void NutriControl::OnMyBasketItemChanged(Windows::UI::Xaml::DependencyObject const& d, Windows::UI::Xaml::DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs const& /* e */)
    {
       // still unimplemented
    }
```

```
// NutriControl.Xaml
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content=">">
            <Button.Flyout>
                <Flyout>
                    <Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="FlyoutPresenter">
                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Disabled"/>
                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
                            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="True"/>
                            <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Cycle"/>
                        </Style>
                    </Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
                    <StackPanel>
 see here-------->      <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind MyBasketItem.Nutrition.Amount, Mode=OneWay}"></TextBlock>
 and here-------->      <ListBox ItemsSource="{x:Bind MyBasketItem.Nutrition.Elems}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:BasketItemNutriElem">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{x:Bind Nutrient, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{x:Bind Amount, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Flyout>
            </Button.Flyout>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
```

This worked. MyBasketItem (-> Nutrition) and (->Elems->BasketItemNutriElem) are both sub-viewmodels of type BasketItem, so I've successfully passed local instances of viewmodels from MainPage.Xaml to a user control.

Answer (score 0):

> So I need to figure out a way to either pass in BasketItem, or BasketItemNutri, from the MainPage into custom user control.

You has placed `NutriDetailsControl` in the  `DataTemplate`, so you can't use `x:Bind` to bind property in the code behind directly. For this scenario, the better way is that use bind element name then find it's `DataContext`

```
MyBasketItem="{Binding ElementName=ItemList,Path=DataContext.MyBasketItem}"
```

Please note, you need specific current page as page's DataContext.

```
public MainPage()
{
   
    this.InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}
```

For more detail please refer this case [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60850757/uwp-button-click-from-listviewitem/60860411#60860411) .