# How to Bind to Oustide of x:DataType in DataTemplate?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a DataTemplate with `x:DataType="myModel"` now i want to bind to property outside of DataType How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a DataTemplate with x:DataType="myModel" now i want to bind to property outside of DataType How can i do this?

If you want to access the property that out of `DataType`, please using `Binding ElementName=Control Name` then access the the outside propety from the parent `DataContext`

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="RootGrid">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" x:Name="MyListView">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                            Margin="0,0,30,0" 
                            Content="Favorite" 
                            Command="{Binding ElementName=MyListView,Path=DataContext.BtnCommand}" 
                            CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

And here is similar [case reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60850757/uwp-button-click-from-listviewitem/60860411#60860411) that you could refer.