# How to Cleanup the ListViewItem's state before they get reused?

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp

The problem is that the listview uses virtualization, and when the items change their appearance, they remain after list is refreshed. This is an answer from Microsoft engineers

> This is caused by the virtualizing nature of ListView's default panel
> (ItemsStackPanel). It essentially reuses the same ListViewItem
> (containers) and when it reuses them it might be in a state that is
> not correct. When you use stack panel, there is no virtualization and
> every item gets a container (no reuse) which as you can imagine can
> get very time consuming if there are many items in your list. You can
> try using PrepareContainerForItemOverride,
> ClearContainerForItemOverride to cleanup the ListViewItem's state
> before they get reused. Even better would be to use the
> ContainerContentChanging event and do it there so you don't need a
> derived type.

Unfortunately I could not find an example for using the **PrepareContainerForItemOverride**, **ClearContainerForItemOverride** and **ContainerContentChanging** methods.

How can I Clear the  ListViewItem's state in the ContainerContentChanging?

UPDATE:

UserControl:

```
<Grid>
        <SwipeControl x:Name="ListViewSwipeContainer">
            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock
                    Margin="10,5,200,5"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    FontSize="18"
                    Text="{Binding ElementName=subsceneView, Path=Title}"
                    TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                <AppBarButton
                    Name="OpenFolderButton"
                    Grid.RowSpan="2"
                    MinWidth="75"
                    Margin="10,0,10,0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Click="OpenFolderButton_Click"
                    Icon="OpenLocal"
                    IsTabStop="False"
                    Label="Open Folder"
                    Visibility="Collapsed"/>

                <AppBarButton
                    Name="DownloadHoverButton"
                    Grid.RowSpan="2"
                    Margin="10,0,10,0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Click="DownloadHoverButton_Click"
                    Icon="Download"
                    IsTabStop="False"
                    Label="Download"
                    Visibility="Collapsed"/>

            </Grid>
        </SwipeControl>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="HoveringStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="HoverButtonsHidden"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="HoverButtonsShown">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="DownloadHoverButton.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    </Grid>
```

code behind:

```
public sealed partial class SubsceneUserControl : UserControl
    {
        #region DependencyProperty
       

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Title", typeof(string), typeof(SubsceneUserControl),
            new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

        public string Title
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TitleProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TitleProperty, value); }
        }

        
        #endregion
        public SubsceneUserControl()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void UserControl_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Pointer.PointerDeviceType == Windows.Devices.Input.PointerDeviceType.Mouse ||
                e.Pointer.PointerDeviceType == Windows.Devices.Input.PointerDeviceType.Pen)
            {
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(sender as Control, "HoverButtonsShown", true);
            }
        }

        private void UserControl_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(sender as Control, "HoverButtonsHidden", true);
        }

        private void OpenFolderButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void DownloadHoverButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFolderButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            DownloadHoverButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
```

and this is my listview

```
<ListView
            x:Name="listv"
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind Subtitles, Mode=OneWay}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:SubsceneDownloadModel">
                    <local:SubsceneUserControl Title="{x:Bind Title}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

private void AddItems()
        {
            Subtitles?.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Subtitles.Add(new SubsceneDownloadModel { Title = "Test " + i });

            }
        }
```

Comment: Why not implement  INotifyPropertyChanged for class to disable erroneously  reused behavior？

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT i dont know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ListViewItem's state before they get reused

For this  scenario, the better way is using mvvm binding and implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for model class. For more detail please refer to [Data binding in depth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth).

For example

**Model Class**

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Model(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
   private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool _visible;
    public bool Visible
    {

        get => _visible;
        set
        {
            _visible = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            // PropertyChanged is always null.
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**Xaml**

```
<ListView x:Name="MyList">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <SymbolIcon
            x:Name="MySbl"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            Symbol="Accept"
            Visibility="{Binding Visible}" />
            </StackPanel>

        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**Usage**

```
MyList.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<Model> {
        new Model("hello"),
          new Model("hello1"),
            new Model("hello2"),
              new Model("hello3"),
                new Model("hello4"),
                  new Model("hello5"),
                    new Model("hello6"),
        };
```

Comment: Thank you, but my application is as follows
After clicking on the button in the list view, the operation will be performed and if it is successful, the button must be hidden. Since it is not easy to access the components of the data template or later change the data collection, I have defined the data template in usercontrol In your method, how can I update the desired record and hide or show the button after the operation? To better understand the status of the program, I will update the first post please see it

Comment: We suggest you binding button's Visibility view bool value, if you want to hidden this button, please invoke the button command method and setter current item's bool value as false. here is similar case [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60860411/7254781)you could refer to